# How can I use jest on React using npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, npm, jestjs

My application is made using create react app and npm. In the jest's official documentation, https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react , they only have information about testing CRA apps using yarn. Does this mean we cannot use jest to test our React app using npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jest with CRA, in fact it's already built-in to CRA.

Try run `npm test`

Read more details here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests